# Return progress status when drawing a large NetworkX graph

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, graph, networkx

- I have a large graph that I'm drawing that is taking a long time to
  process.
- Is it possible to return a `status`, `current_node`, or `percentage` of the current status of the drawing?
- I'm not looking to incrementally draw the network as all I'm doing it is saving it to a high dpi image.

Here's an example of the code I'm using:

```
path = nx.shortest_path(G, source=u'1234', target=u'98765')
path_edges = zip(path, path[1:])
pos = nx.spring_layout(G) 
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,nodelist=path,node_color='r') 
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edgelist=path_edges,edge_color='r',width=10) 
plt.axis('equal')
plt.savefig('prototype_map.png', dpi=1000)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the only way to do it is to accommodate the source code of draw function to print something saying 10%, 20% complete.... But when I checked the [source code of draw_networkx_nodes & draw_networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/_modules/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.html#draw_networkx_nodes), I realized that it is not a straight forward task as the draw function stores the positions (nodes and edges) in a numpy array, send it to the ax.scatter function of matplotlib [(sourcecode)](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py) which is a bit hard to manipulate without messing something up. The only thing I can think of is to change:

```
xy = numpy.asarray([pos[v] for v in nodelist]) # In draw_networkx_nodes function
```

To

```
xy = []
count = 0
for v in nodelist:
    xy.append(pos[v])
    count +=1
    if (count == len(nodelist)):
        print '50% of nodes completed'
print '100% of nodes completed'
xy = numpy.asarray(xy)
```

Similarly when draw_network_edges is called, to indicate progress in edges drawing. I am not sure how far from truth this will be because I do not know how much time is spent in the ax.scatter function. I also, looked in the source code of the scatter function but I could not pin point a loop or something to print an indication that some progress has been done.

Comment: That sounds like enough to report status by inserting a logging statement at the beginning of each of these sections: like "Status: storing %d nodes"%len(nodes).  One could even add some timing statements at the same places and set up test cases to understand the order of the problem experimentally.

Comment: Yes indeed, you may look into the scatter source code  of matplotlib to get more detailed status. Another idea is to do some experiments to get the time elapsed during the draw function (that is by capturing time before and after calling the function)  and then divide the average time by the number of nodes to know time taken for each node. This can be done formally using profiling here https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html

Comment: It would be also more more visual, if after knowing the time for each node to run a parallel thread that run for time = number of nodes* time for each node and prints 10%, 20% ... Anyway, let us know if it worked it is an interesting issue.

Comment: I think although the answer is very valid, I think it's over and above what I intend to do and might park  the idea for now and see if it's a true "Requirement" or a "nice to have". I really don't want to muck around with the NetworkX base code

Answer (score 0):

Some layout functions accept `pos` argument to conduct incremental work. We can use this fact to split the computation into chunks and draw a progress bar using [tqdm](https://tqdm.github.io)

```py
def plot_graph(g, iterations=50, pos=None, k_numerator=None, figsize=(10, 10)):
    if k_numerator is None:
        k = None
    else:
        k = k_numerator / np.sqrt(g.number_of_nodes())
    with tqdm(total=iterations) as pbar:
        step = 5
        iterations_done = 0
        while iterations_done < iterations:
            pos = nx.layout.fruchterman_reingold_layout(
                g, iterations=step, pos=pos, k=k
            )
            iterations_done += step
            pbar.update(step)
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize, dpi=120)
        nx.draw_networkx(
            g,
            pos,
           
        )
    return fig, pos
```